# Libchart PHP won't display

Tags: php, mysqli

I just wanted to know what is the error in my code, I tried first my query if it's working and it does. However, as I put in into codes, the chart won't display. By the way I'm using Libchart PHP.
Thank you in advance.

```
<?php
    include 'libchart/libchart/classes/libchart.php';
    require '../connection/connect.php';

    header("Content-type: image/png");

    $chart = new PieChart(500, 300);
    $query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jobseeker_reg WHERE gender='Male') AS Male, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM jobseeker_reg WHERE gender='Female') AS Female");
    $male=$query[0]['Male'];
    $female=$query[0]['Female'];
    $dataSet = new XYDataSet();
    $dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Male", $male));
    $dataSet->addPoint(new Point("Female", $female));
    $chart->setDataSet($dataSet);

    $chart->setTitle("Number of Jobseekers (by Gender)");
    $chart->render();
?>
```

Comment: Comment out `header("Content-type: image/png")` and look for messages + `mysqli_query` not enough - http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php and read carefully - http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Comment: $con variable in my mysqli_query is already declared in my connect.php, no need to code it again I guess, cause it's working on my other webpage.

Comment: You did not read the link. `mysqli_query` returns not an array. `For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object` Further data should be obtained by the methods and examples shown in my previous links (`fetch_array`, `fetch_assoc`, `fetch_object` and etc..)